# What is this old biplane on a float?

Tags: aviation-history, aircraft-identification

I'm hoping for some help in identifying the plane in these two photographs I found in my father's collection.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Was he old enough to have taken them, or do you believe they were passed on to him already? In any case, it might help to add the general location where it most likely was taken (if not known, maybe you can narrow it down - e.g. which part of the world was your father based/travelled in).

Comment: Thanks for taking time to ask the questions. He didn't take the photos. I imagine he bought them at a flea market.

Answer (score 1):

It looks a lot like a variant or a copy of the [Curtiss Model E](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curtiss_Model_E) (aka Curtiss A1) from 1912:

[image]

There is a [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GpJr6jDGEQw) of it flying in 2011.

Comment: Hmm. Close... but I think the tail and some of the struts are different.

Comment: I agree. That’s why I said “variant or copy”. It could be a prototype too...

Comment: Indeed. Could be. Or maybe they ran out of square wood for the rudder. :)

Comment: Clearly Curtiss, though; Glen was the inventor of ailerons (as opposed to wing warping for roll control).